# openpyxl - write-only worksheet fails to add table

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to write a new workbook, with 1 sheet and add a table to that sheet. AFAIK it should be possible, this commit should do it https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/commits/6f440b0ed398

But when I try to do that, it fails with the message:

```
KeyError: 'Unknown relationship: None'
```

My code snippet is:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table

wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

ws.append(['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
ws.append(['val11','val12','val13','val14'])
ws.append(['val21','val22','val23','val24'])
ws.append(['val31','val32','val33','val34'])
ws.append(['val41','val42','val43','val44'])

table = Table(displayName="basetable", ref="A1:D4")
ws.add_table(table)
wb.save('table.xlsx')
```

The full traceback is:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    wb.save('table.xlsx')

File "./site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 354, in save
    save_dump(self, filename)

File "./site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 313, in save_dump
    writer.save(filename)

File "./site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 266, in save
    self.write_data()

File "./site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 83, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()

File "./site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 229, in _write_worksheets
    ws._rels[t._rel_id].Target = t.path

File "./site-packages/openpyxl/packaging/relationship.py", line 97, in __getitem__    
    raise KeyError("Unknown relationship: {0}".format(key))
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: i'm using python 2.7 and tested this code with current release (2.4.8) and pre-release (2.5.0a3) versions of openpyxl on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score -3):

> **Question**: write-only worksheet fails to add table

Tried your Example got:

```
AttributeError: 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'add_table'
```

Removed `write_only=True`, works OK.

> **Output**:
>   [image]

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2  and 2.7.9 - openpyxl: 2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As pointed in my original post, the `add_table` method was added as a fix for issue [729](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/729), and included on version [2.4.4](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/changes.html#id23), so if you could test your code on an updated version I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @ClaudioNovoa: Sorry couldn't test with other Version. If you add a Note to your Question that it's possible to use `add_table` **without** `write_only=True` I will delete this Answer.